# How do I fix cfdisk error: "Partition ends in final partial cylinder"?

Tags: partitioning, arch-linux

I want to install Arch Linux on my desktop, it is going to be dual-booted with Windows.

I loaded the installation CD, but when I started `cfdisk` to partition my hard drive it gave me the following error.

```
root@arch # cfdisk
FATAL ERROR: Primairy parititon 1, partition ends in the final partial cylinder
```

How can I troubleshoot and fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to start from scratch, delete all partitions, Configure new partitions and install your OS's.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=257064

EDIT:

It could have something to do with the New Advanced Format hard drives,

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=813368

.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I suppose there is no other way. But do you know what the error means by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, and the solution was to use gparted to resize/move the existing partitions aligned to cylinder boundaries. Gparted has an option to align partitions to cylinder boundaries when setting the resize options.